# How to create a XML File from Datagridview control in Windows Form application?

Tags: datagridview

I am creating a XML file in Windows application, In the form I have DataGridView control, user clicks on the row and enter text or select values from Combo boxes.
I create rows programatically, say after 10 rows have been created, i want
to save that information to a XML file so that next time my application runs,
the datagridview is populated again... What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Got the nice solution:

```
    private void saveItemDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("itemstable"); 

        for(int i=0; i<itemDataGridView.ColumnCount; i++){
            dt.Columns.Add(itemDataGridView.Columns[i].Name,typeof(System.String));
        }

        DataRow myrow ;
        int icols = itemDataGridView.Columns.Count; 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in this.itemDataGridView.Rows) { 
            myrow = dt.NewRow(); 
            for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++) { 

                myrow[i] = drow.Cells[i].Value; 
            } 
            dt.Rows.Add(myrow); 
        } 

        dt.WriteXml("items.xml");

    }
```